# Can't delete or find saved wrong passwords in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Somehow my Chrome saved some wrong passwords for a website below:
https://www.nautica.com/account (pic 1)
[https://imgur.com/a/UB6tSqv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKaWm.png)

And these password seem to be from the account resgistration page (pic 2)
[https://imgur.com/a/5aKbw2s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu2Dh.png)

However, I can't find any of them in password manager, nor can I update them:
(pic3)
[https://imgur.com/a/2CiuPzj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG5z1.png)

Could anyone please enlighten me how I can resolve such an annoying issue? I really don't want to manually input my password every time I log in.

Normally, if a password is properly saved, you should be able to see this icon:
[How a saved password looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8m66.png)

but on the page where only wrong combos are memories, there is no such a thing:
[I don't know where Chrome pulls the password from?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu8uH.png)

Thank everyone in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I had a look and doubt things are are even relevant: https://imgur.com/a/JK9NiWm the username is not even an email address (blurred but I know they are not the same)

Comment: There is nothing relevant to the Chrome password issue in Windows Credentials: https://imgur.com/a/KQ5KbDH You can see the email address is @live.com, but I use my Gmail for Nautica.com. I doubt OneDrive is related either. These have a category of either Log-on session or Local computer

Comment: Hmm.. what does Web site facility mean? I tried to reset my password, but so far I haven't received any email from Nautica yet due to some strange reason. I also use AdGuard, but I suspended it for Nautica.com

Comment: There were occasions where Chrome failed to recognise the password field and thus didn't offer to help save it - but in my case, Chrome didn't suggest a password saving and the username and password choices came from my registration page - however I changed my password after my registration and the new password does end with u, but the one selectable ending with u is seen as incorrect by Nautica.com

Comment: I had to contact their live chat support and they manually reset it for me. But still, Chrome does offer to memorise my new password while still saves the old wrong ones.. so annoying